# problems building cascading lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

I have a json that comes from the server (can't be changed) and I need to build a nested unordered list menu.

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremybolanos/me6SM/1/) - warning! takes a long time to run and this is just sample data - the real stuff is considerably bigger.

somehow it gets messed up and I end up with multiple things out of place and it takes forever to run.

the Code:

```
$.each(jData, function (k, v) {
    var vendor = JSON.stringify(k);
    vendor = vendor.replace(/"/g, '');
    var vendorRow = '<li data-vendor="' + vendor + '" class="listItem v">' + vendor + '</li>';
    $('ul#vendors').append(vendorRow);
    $('ul#vendors li[data-vendor="'+vendor+'"]').append('<ul class="sub hide"/>');
    var getArea = _.groupBy(jData[vendor], 'area');
    $.each(getArea, function(k, v) {
        var area = JSON.stringify(k);
        area = area.replace(/"/g,'');
        var thisArea = '<li data-area="'+area+'" class="listItem a">'+area+'</li>';
        $('ul#vendors li[data-vendor="'+vendor+'"] ul.sub').append(thisArea);
        $('ul#vendors li[data-area="'+area+'"]').append('<ul class="sub hide"/>');
        var getRegion = _.groupBy(getArea[area], 'region');
        $.each(getRegion, function(k, v) {
            var region = JSON.stringify(k);
            region = region.replace(/"/g,'');
            var thisRegion = '<li data-region="'+region+'" class="listItem a">'+region+'</li>';
            $('ul#vendors li[data-area="'+area+'"] ul.sub').append(thisRegion);
            $('ul#vendors li[data-region="'+region+'"]').append('<ul class="sub hide"/>');
            var getMarket = _.groupBy(getRegion[region], 'market');
            $.each(getMarket, function(k, v) {
                var market = JSON.stringify(k);
                market = market.replace(/"/g,'');
                var thisMarket = '<li data-market="'+market+'" class="listItem m">'+market+'</li>';
                $('ul#vendors li[data-region="'+region+'"] ul.sub').append(thisMarket);
                $('ul#vendors li[data-market="'+market+'"]').append('<ul class="sub hide"/>');
                var getSwitch = _.groupBy(getMarket[market], 'switch');
                $.each(getSwitch, function(k, v) {
                    var vSwitch = JSON.stringify(k);
                    vSwitch = vSwitch.replace(/"/g,'');
                    var thisSwitch = '<li data-switch="'+vSwitch+'" class="listItem s">'+vSwitch+'</li>';
                    $('ul#vendors li[data-market="'+market+'"] ul.sub').append(thisSwitch);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Example output:

```
<div id="chartWizard">
    <ul id="vendors">
        <li class="listItem v" data-vendor="levdore">
            levdore
            <ul class="sub hide">
                <li class="listItem a" data-area="Midwest">
                    Midwest
                    <ul class="sub hide">...</ul>
                    <ul class="sub hide">...</ul>
                    <ul class="sub hide">...</ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The list seems to fall apart at the 2nd ul.sub with multiple ul.sub elements where there should only be one.

Comment: Your code is very repetitive. Try to figure out how to simplify it.

Comment: Code Review would be a better place for this

Comment: hint: recursive function

Comment: I'm writing it out long form looking for the problem.  Once I've resolved the methodology I'll write the supporting functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think that reworking your code to logically traverse your objects using recursion is the right way to go. Somewhere along the line your iterating multiple times over your objects which is why its taking soooo long for this to load.  I reworked your example and here's what I came up with.  You can probably iron it out further to make it more readable.

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/me6SM/9/

```
doRecursive(jData,null,$('ul#vendors'),0);

function doRecursive(grp,parent,selector,depth){
    $.each(grp, function(k,v) {
        var item = JSON.stringify(k).replace(/"/g,'');
        var element = ['area','region','market','switch'][depth];
        var thisSelector = 'data-' + element + '="'+item+'"';
        var thisItem = $('<li ' + thisSelector + ' class="listItem '+ (element ? element[0] : '') +'">'+item+'</li>');
        selector.append(thisItem);
        var childList = $('<ul class="sub hide"/>');
        thisItem.append(childList);
        if(!element){return;}
        var next = _.groupBy(grp[item], element );
        doRecursive(next,item, childList , depth + 1);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that's sort of what I'm working on now since stepping back and revisioning the output